# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ Verification of a Lipschitz Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a Lipschitz function provided that there is a nonnegative number $C$ such that

$|f(u)-f(v)|\le C|u-v|$ for all $u,v\in D$.

Show that a Lipschitz function satisfies the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ criterion on $D$.

---

In order for this to be true, for $\epsilon>0$, we must find a $\delta>0$ such that

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ $\hspace{10pt}$ if $\hspace{10pt}$ $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

If we let $u=x$ and $v=x_0$, then we have

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le C|x-x_0|$ for all $x\in D$, but I'm not sure where to go after this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What value of $\delta$ (in terms of $\epsilon, C, x_0$) will result in $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\delta={\varepsilon \over C}$.

Then $|x - x_0| < {\varepsilon \over C}$, which means $C|x - x_0| < {\varepsilon}$.

And since $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le C|x-x_0|$, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< {\varepsilon}$.